# All applications requests are dispatched by the same front controller in symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony1, http-status-code-404, front-controller

I'm just facing some weird situation. I have a project in symfony 1.4 which has two applications (api & admin). I use to work in two OS, on my office I have ubuntu and window 7 at home.

At office (ubuntu 11.10) everything is working fine, while at home (Window 7 with XAMPP) when I request an url from the API app (let say `http://www.domain.local/api_dev.php/users.xml`) the front controller giving the answer is the admin one (admin_dev.php). As consequence I get 404 errors since that route is not defined in admin app but in API.

I have discarded error in project copy or else since I'm using git to do version control. The api application is powered by the [sfDoctrineRestGeneratorPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineRestGeneratorPlugin) and used to work fine, I did not notice when introduced the error since at office everything was going ok. I have tried clearing the cache, cloning again the project from that at office with no success.

It doesn't seem to me a XAMPP problem since it was working ok before and requesting `http://www.domain.local/api_dev.php/product.xml` give me these logs entries:

admin_dev.log

`Apr 03 14:42:09 symfony [err] {sfError404Exception} Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/product.xml" (/).`

api_dev.log [Empty log file]

If I request: 
`http://www.domain.local/api_dev.php/` it send me to the admin home page, but if I request:
`http://www.domain.local/api_dev.php` (notice the lack of slash) it goes to the default index route in API. And in api_dev.log I get the expected entries. This make me think in a route issue but no ideas come up.

In both app I have default homepage route like this:

-API-

```
homepage:
  url:   /
  param: { module: product, action: index }
```

-Admin-

```
homepage:
  url:   /
  param: { module: ouradmin, action: index }
```

Thanks for listen and for the time
Any help or advice will be really appreciated.

Thanks
David

Comment: Smells like a xampp configuration issue to me...

Comment: I just edited the question to give you answers. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

After days living with this, I listen to greg0ire words:

> Smells like a xampp configuration issue to me...

I did update my version of Xampp, also removed any temporary file I could find. After re cloning the project again, everything went to normality :P

I guess I will never know what happened there, so newbie :P ...

Thanks for listen and sorry for the time taken

David